# Python: Terminate an imported script without killing the script that is doing the import

Tags: python, selenium

Sorry whoever reads this before I finish; it posted before I wanted to...

I have a ton of Selenium tests that I'd like to run overnight.  However, each test, as of now, requires me to login to the server (which is slow - takes about half the duration of the entire test).  I'm trying to avoid this by using the same IE driver.  When I have a test that critically fails, I want to stop that particular test and move on.  However, I can't seem to do that without killing all of the tests at once.

For example, here's a script that simplifies the issue I'm having (I'd have to paste too much code in here otherwise):

```
# Wrapper.py:
driver = webdriver.Ie()
try:
    import test1
    test1.setup(driver)
except Exception as e:
    print e

try:
    import test2
    test2.setup(driver)
except Exception as e:
    print e

try:
    import test3
    test3.setup(driver)
except Exception as e:
    print e


# test1.py
def setup(driver):
    # do stuff in test1

# test2.py
def setup(driver):
    # do stuff in test2

# test3.py
def setup(driver):
    # do stuff in test3
```

This may look dumb, and it very well so could be, but it would allow me to run multiple Selenium tests using a constant IE browser.  However, there are occasions where a test needs to be killed (whether it be a critical error or too many errors).  This would typically be done using:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

However, using test2.py as the example, using that command will kill the test2.py script AND the wrapper.py script; I would like it to only kill test2, allowing me to continue to test3.  It's similar to having a batch file that would call each test separately and wait until the previous has finished.  However, in the batch file, the driver cannot be passed in as if it were the same driver for each.

I'm using:

```
Python 2.7
Windows 7 64-bit
Selenium 2.44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually you would terminate a test early by returning False

```
# test2.py
def setup(driver):
    # do stuff in test2
    if should_fail:
       return False
    ...
    return True
```

however its entirely possible I didnt understand your question properly...

another alternative is to just raise an exception

```
def setup(driver):
    assert ContitionIsTrue,"Failed Condition Check!"
```

this will be caught by your exception handler

Comment: aha! the assertion worked for what I was trying to do.  Thanks